# The .justify-content-center class isn't working when applied to .row (Bootstrap 4.4.1)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
          <ul>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
              <li>Example List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <p class="copyright pt-5 text-muted">Blah blah blah.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the latest Boostrap 4 (4.4.1) and want to center the columns within the top .row. I've had trouble doing so. When I add .justify-content-center to the row, there is absolutely no effect at all (the set of columns remain flushed left at the point where my container begins). I've tried other variations such as .justify-content-end to see if anything is working. I also tried creating my own css class with `justify-content: center;` and using it instead of the Bootstrap class. No luck. The second .row centers fine.

Comment: its becouse are you using 4 col-sm-3 the it takes all line space just try to change to col-sm-2

Comment: You can use mx-auto to center on columns in bootstrap. If your elements are inline you can use the text-center class on the column.

Comment: Thanks @JasarOrion and @Steve. I reduced the spacing to col-sm-2 and `justify-content-around` centers and nicely spaces out the colums for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-2">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the main issue is that if the columns span the entire width of the row (across the 12 col grid), one won't be able to see them centered. If you reduce the amount of space you take up across the 12 grids, you'll then be able to see the centering effect. You can then also add margins and paddings to the columns if you like.